# jQuery mobile footer with different rules than header

Tags: jquery-mobile

[The documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html) says

```
The footer bar has the same basic structure as the header except it uses the data-role attribute value of footer.
```

But [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/mXjHJ/83/) shows that I can't put controls in the footer the same way as I can the header.

Q: How can I write a footer such that there is text followed by an h1 tag followed by text, and they are all on the same line?

Comment: You could manually style it by floating your buttons and reducing the width of your h4 tag, for example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/85/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same classes jQM applies to the header elements (`ui-btn-left, ui-title, ui-btn-right`):

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <a href="JavaScript:;" class="ui-btn-left" >c</a>
    <h3 class="ui-title">Footer</h3>
    <a href="JavaScript:;" class="ui-btn-right" >d</a>
</div>
```

Here is your updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mXjHJ/86/**